# Selenium Web Driver Java codes are not reading xpath / Class id / link id from "Object.Properties" file stored in the src folder under package folder

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng, oracle12c, ojdbc

I am using Selenium Web Driver and Java in the Eclipse and I am trying to read xpath/Class id / link id from "Object.Properties" file stored in the src folder under package folder and populate test data from database. However, after reading 2nd property from following property file script is not reading property for Email, Pwd and Submit. I am not able to figure it out why script is not reading these property.

My Script will identify web field, button, link using xpath / Class id / link id from "Object.Properties" file stored in the src folder under package folder. And for web page field script will bring test data from database and populate them in the particular field on the web page.

Following property are stored in the "Object.Properties" file and this property file is stored in the src folder under package folder:

```
URL = http://web.com/user-portal
ClickOnLoginLink = //*[@id='app']/div/main/section/ul/li[1]/a
Email = //input[@name='username']
Pwd = //input[@name='password']
Submit = //button[@name='loginButton']
```

Following Failure exception display:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@name='username']"}
Command duration or timeout: 12 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.52.0', revision: '4c2593c', time: '2016-02-11 19:03:33'
System info: host: 'CAEITVDI-085', ip: '172.23.212.109', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_66'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=true, rotatable=false, handlesAlerts=true, databaseEnabled=true, version=41.0.1, platform=WINDOWS, nativeEvents=false, acceptSslCerts=true, webStorageEnabled=true, locationContextEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
Session ID: d0672bd2-d9d0-413e-a734-1865a9cce733
*** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//input[@name='username']}
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:678)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:363)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByXPath(RemoteWebDriver.java:500)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath.findElement(By.java:361)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:355)
    at com.provider.ProApp.testUserNamePassword(ProApp.java:76)
    at com.provider.ProApp.setUpConnection(ProApp.java:42)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:85)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:639)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:816)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1124)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:108)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:774)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:624)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:359)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:354)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:312)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:261)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1215)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1140)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1048)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:112)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:205)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:176)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@name='username']"}
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.52.0', revision: '4c2593c', time: '2016-02-11 19:03:33'
System info: host: 'CAEITVDI-085', ip: '172.23.212.109', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_66'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at <anonymous class>.FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElementInternal_(file:///C:/Users/SAV19734/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous6689352326673970234webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10723)
    at <anonymous class>.FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElement(file:///C:/Users/SAV19734/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous6689352326673970234webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10732)
    at <anonymous class>.DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h(file:///C:/Users/SAV19734/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous6689352326673970234webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12614)
    at <anonymous class>.DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_(file:///C:/Users/SAV19734/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous6689352326673970234webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12619)
    at <anonymous class>.DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/<(file:///C:/Users/SAV19734/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous6689352326673970234webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12561)
```

Here is my Base class Code:

```
package com.provider;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Properties;
import oracle.net.ns.NetException;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;


public class BaseClass {

    static WebDriver driver;

     @BeforeSuite
     public void setup() throws InterruptedException, IOException{

         driver=new FirefoxDriver();

         driver.manage().window().maximize();


         Properties obj = new Properties();

         FileInputStream objfile = new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir") +"\\src\\com\\provider\\Object.Properties");
         obj.load(objfile);

        driver.get(obj.getProperty("URL"));
     }

}
```

Here is my Extended class Code:

```
package com.provider;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Properties;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;



public class ProApp extends BaseClass{



@Test
    public void setUpConnection() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException, FileNotFoundException, InterruptedException, IOException {

         String driver_DBPath = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@Host:Port:SID";
         String DB_username = "*****";
         String DB_password = "*****";
     String Query = "select * from Table";
     Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(driver_DBPath, DB_username, DB_password);
     Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
     ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(Query);


     while(rs.next()){

         String Email = rs.getString("CLAIM_NUMBER");
         String Pwd = rs.getString("INDIVIDUAL_NUM");

         testUserNamePassword(Email, Pwd);
     }

    }

    @Test(priority=1)
    public void clickLoginLink() throws InterruptedException, IOException {

    Properties obj = new Properties();

    FileInputStream objfile = new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir") +"\\src\\com\\provider\\Object.Properties");
    obj.load(objfile);


    Thread.sleep(1000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(obj.getProperty("ClickOnLoginLink"))).click();
    Thread.sleep(1000);

    }

    @Test(priority=2)
    public void testUserNamePassword(String Email1, String Pwd1) throws InterruptedException, IOException {

    Thread.sleep(1000);
    Properties obj = new Properties();

    FileInputStream objfile = new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir") +"\\src\\com\\provider\\Object.Properties");
    obj.load(objfile);

    Thread.sleep(1000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(obj.getProperty("Email"))).clear();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(obj.getProperty("Email"))).sendKeys(Email1);
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(obj.getProperty("Pwd"))).clear();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(obj.getProperty("Pwd"))).sendKeys(Pwd1);
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(obj.getProperty("Submit"))).click();
    Thread.sleep(1000);

    }

    @Test(priority=3)
    public void loginVerify() throws InterruptedException, IOException{

        Properties obj = new Properties();

        FileInputStream objfile = new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir") +"\\src\\com\\provider\\Object.Properties");
        obj.load(objfile);

        Assert.assertEquals("Wel Come To Testing World!!!", driver.findElement(By.xpath(obj.getProperty("WelComeToTestingWorld"))).getText());

    }    

    @Test(priority=4)
    public void logonVerify() throws InterruptedException, IOException{

        Properties obj = new Properties();

        FileInputStream objfile = new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir") +"\\src\\com\\provider\\Object.Properties");
        obj.load(objfile);

        WebElement DashboardHeader = driver.findElement(By.xpath(obj.getProperty("WelComeToTestingWorld")));
        DashboardHeader.getText().equals("Wel Come To Testing World!!!");

    }

}
```

Comment: what was the error message in console?

Comment: I updated post with failure exception. I double checked web element that provided in property file. Actually, script is able to identify first two web element and able to reach till Email and Password field. However, script is not able to locate Email and Password field using web element stored in the property file. I provided property file path under @Test(priority=2) annotation in the script in the extended class.

Comment: seems like problem with finding web element via Xpath. check whether your Xpaths are correct.seems like other stuff are correct.maybe this will help you http://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/read-data-from-properties-file-using-java-selenium. try some tool to locate web elements Xpath.(https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/element-locator-for-webdriv/)

Comment: I am using Mozilla Firefox fire bug console for identifying Xpath / Class Id / link ld and all and fire bug console is successfully identifying the right web element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I figure it out that I haven't given Priority where I have provided database connection method information so that when script is running then script is following TestNG framework in order to execute test and script start executing Test(priority=1), Test(priority=2) and so on... And for database connection where I only provided "Test" before starting database connection method. I should have also prioritize database connection method as Test(priority=2). So just prioritize database connection method resolve my issue.